# A subset $D$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is called open if none of its boundary points are in the subset, that is, if $\delta D \cap D = \varnothing$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A subset $D$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is called open if none of its boundary points are in the subset, that is, if $\delta D \cap D = \varnothing$.

This is in the context of multivariable maxima and minima.

My question is, what does $\delta D \cap D$ of $\delta D \cap D = \varnothing$ mean? I was under the impression that $\cap$ stood for 'intersect', which basically means AND. However, I'm having trouble understanding what it means in this case, as $\delta D \cap D$.

I'd appreciate any clarification. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right. $\delta D$ is the boundary of $D$, which consists of points $x$ so that any ball centered at $x$ contains both points of $D$ and points outside $D$. To say that $D$ is open is to say that it contains none of its boundary points. (So the set of points $x\in\Bbb R^2$ with $\|x\|<1$ is open, but the set of points $x$ with $\|x\|\le 1$ is not.)

Comment: But why does it say $\delta D$ AND $D$ then? Since its open, which means it doesn't include the boundary, shouldn't it just say $D$, since $\delta D$ represents the boundary?

Comment: It says $\delta D \cap D = \varnothing$.  The left side is the set of boundary points of $D$ that are in $D$.  The right side is the empty set.  So this means exactly the same as "none of the boundary points of $D$ are in $D$", i.e. it is a restatement of your definition of open.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"$\delta D\cap D$" means "all the points contained in both $\delta D$ and $D$. "$\delta D$" means the "boundary of $D$". So if $D$ does not contain any of the points found in the boundary $\delta D$, we say it is open.